# gnuplot multiple lines with Time on X axis

Tags: gnuplot

I've had a look through questions but still can't get this working.

My data set is like this:

```
[date] , [%cpu] , [mem]
23:00:39 , 21.9 , 2.1
23:00:44 , 21.8 , 2.1
23:00:49 , 21.8 , 2.1
23:00:54 , 21.8 , 2.1
23:00:59 , 21.7 , 2.1
```

My Gnuplot statements (just started using for this data) is:

```
set timefmt "%H:%m:%s"
set xdata time
set datafile sep ','
plot '/tmp/info' using 2 title 'cpu' with lines, '/tmp/info' using 3 title 'memory%' with lines
```

I get the following error:

> ```
>     Need full using spec for x time data
> ```

I've tried autoscale x , but I'm a bit lost, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time data requires that you always specify all columns to be used. (Note also the corrected `timefmt`):

```
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set datafile sep ','
set style data lines
plot '/tmp/info' using 1:2 title 'cpu', '' using 1:3 title 'memory%'
```

The reason for this is, that the `timefmt` may also contain spaces, so that the data used for the time axis may come from two columns. Consider the following modified data file:

```
23:00:39 06/08/13 21.9 2.1
23:00:44 06/08/13 21.8 2.1
23:00:49 06/08/13 21.8 2.1
23:00:54 06/08/13 21.8 2.1
23:00:59 06/08/13 21.7 2.1
```

The plotting commands for this format are:

```
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y"
set xdata time 
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set style data lines
plot 'mydata.dat' using 1:3 t 'cpu', '' using 1:4 t 'memory%'
```

To avoid confusion, it is always required that for time data all columns used by the plotting style (here `with lines`) are given explicitely with the `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your plot command look like this instead:

```
plot '/tmp/info' using 1:2 title 'cpu' with lines, '/tmp/info' using 1:3 title 'memory%' with lines
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with gnuplot where I had a data file like:

```
05:07:00    0.0769  0.0769  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
05:08:00    0.2308  0.2308  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

I was trying to use, but it was just not working

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "HH:MM:SS";
plot "wed" using 0:2 t 'wtf" w lines
```

The fix was a couple of things, primarily using the %'s in the timefmt string and only using one letter.  Also using the set format x for the output was key (and using the first column as 1 - though I had tried that also earlier).

This is the minimal output script that is working for me:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
plot "wed" using 1:2 t 'my title' w lines
```