# gnuplot-iostream: no plot when x values are dates

Tags: c++, gnuplot, iostream

I'm defining a vector of pairs as my plotting data:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<std::string,double>> data;
```

The strings represent dates and have the format (using gnuplot convention) **%d/%B/%Y**, e.g. **07/January/2016**.

My code for the plotting is the following:

```cpp
Gnuplot gp;
gp << "set terminal wxt size 1000,800\n";
gp << "set xdata time\n";
gp << "set timefmt '%d/%B/%Y'\n";
gp << "set xrange ['01/January/2016':'30/April/2016']\n";
gp << "plot '-' with lines title 'test'\n";
gp.send1d(data);
```

Unfortunately the plot does not get drawn. What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when plotting any kind of times or dates you *must* explicitely give a `using` statement. If not, you get an error (don't know how gnuplot-iostream reports gnuplot errors).

So try

```
gp << "plot '-' using 1:2 with lines  title 'test'\n";
```

Comment: It was exactly that. I'm new to gnuplot and I thought that the "using" command was only meaningful when reading data from a file. It is though kind of redundant in this case, isn't it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18121824/2604213 for a more detailed explanation why this explicite `using` must always appear for dates.